# Android- Erro "The virtual device got no IP address" Genymotion

Tags: genymotion

Recentemente tive que migrar um projeto android para meu computador Windows o qual fui instalar o emulador **Genymotion** para testar a aplicação, entretanto, após finalizar as configurações do emulador todas as vezes que tento iniciar o dispositivo ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro DHCP Genymotion]

Após algumas pesquisas, me vi que a solução era configurar o DHCP nas placas de rede virtual do virtual box, sendo assim o fiz:

[image: Configurações de rede Virtual Box]

Mesmo assim o meu problema não foi resolvido. Certo tempo depois li uns comentários falando que esse problema poderia ser causado pelo recurso de **Virtualização do processador** que estaria **desativado**, sendo assim fui em tentar ativá-lo no meu setup, entretanto, coincidentemente o meu computador que é um **CCE Onix 7810b+** tem esse recurso desabilitado pela fabricante e a única maneira de conseguir habilita-lo é fazendo um downgrade da bios (o que não quero arriscar pois tenho apenas esse computador para trabalhar e parece ser um processo muito arriscado), via das contas, o fato é que eu já emulei outros máquinas virtuais com arquitetura x86 nesse computador pelo Virtual Box e não consigo aceitar que o emulador do android não possa ser executado em tais condições já que o mesmo é arquitetura x86, gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por esse problema e sabe como contorná-lo?

Também recebo a seguinte mensagem do Virtual Box ao tentar iniciar a máquina virtual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

> Steps 1:

Va até a BIOS  -> System Configuration -> habilite Virtualization Technology -> Save and Exit .

> Steps 2:

Abra Oracle VM VirtualBox -> Selecione o seu simulador -> Va ate as configurações do simulador -> Selecione a aba "General" -> Selecione Basic (sub aba) -> Selecione seu sistema operacional -> Selecione a versão do seu Sistema operacional -> Save and Exit

> Steps 3:

Reinicie o seu Genymotion e inicie- o novamente.

Comment: Lembre-se sempre de colocar a fonte que retirou. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436253/genymotion-the-virtual-device-got-no-ip-address)